# Remotely shut down RabbitMQ server

Tags: rabbitmq

I have been trying to remotely kill a rabbitmq server but haven't been lucky so far. I can easily connect to it and publish and receive messages using the pika library.

Steps I have tried so far:

1. Used RabbitMQ's HTTP API to DELETE a connection

   ```
    /api/connections/name  

    An individual connection. DELETEing it
    willclose the connection. Optionally set the "X-Reason" 
    header when DELETEing to provide a reason.'
   ```

   When I tried something like http://localhost:15672/api/connection/127.0.0.1:31332, I get an error:

   ```
   {"error":"Object Not Found","reason":"\"Not Found\"\n"}
   ```
2. Used rabbitmqadmin locally
3. Tried to use rabbitmqctl to remotely shut down the rabbitmq server

Comment: What OS/Linux distribution/version are you using? For example on `systemd` based systems you can use `systemctl` remotely, as https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Remote.html

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu) on both

Comment: Option 1 is for deleteing client's connection, conencted to RabbitMQ server, so I don't think it can kill RabbitMQ server. Not sure about second option, But third option is quite doable. If you can execute the command "rabbitmqctl stop" on the server remotely, then you can achieve you goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of troubleshooting all over again, I was able to use the HTTP API to kill active connections. The trick was that the whole connection name was to be url encoded.

In my case the connection name was:

```
    127.0.0.1:31332 -> 127.0.0.1:15672
```

So when I tried the following I got an error:

```
    http://localhost:15672/api/connection/127.0.0.1:31332   ==> object not found error
```

It worked only after I URL encoded the connection name and sending a CURL DELETE like this:

```
    http://localhost:15672/api/connection/127.0.0.1%3A31332%20-%3E%20127.0.0.1%3A15672
```

Answer (score 0):

**rabbitmqctl**

Here is how to do that using `rabbitmqctl`

```
set RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS=-setcookie FWQUGISFBWECSKWFVFRP
rabbitmqctl.bat -n rabbit@gabriele-VirtualBox stop
```

**Erlang**

Here is one way to kill a remote node using `Erlang`:

```
erl -setcookie FXQUEISFFRECSKWCVB -sname thekiller@gabriele-VirtualBox
Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
(thekiller@gabriele-VirtualBox)1>  net_adm:ping('rabbit@gabriele-VirtualBox').
pong
(thekiller@gabriele-VirtualBox)2> rpc:call('rabbit@gabriele-VirtualBox', init, stop, []).
ok
(thekiller@gabriele-VirtualBox)3>
```

1. Start `erl` console using your `.erlang.cookie` and with `-sname`
   with same rabbitmq domain (in my case `gabriele-VirtualBox`).
2. Test if you reach the node using ping
3. call `rpc:call('rabbit@gabriele-VirtualBox', init, stop, [])`.

Done, you killed the remote node.